# VS Project Attached to 2 Repositories -- Is there an easy way to detach from one of them?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Here is the situation...

I created a solution locally with 3 projects (a web app created locally, a deployment project for the web app created locally and an open source library connected to a repository on googlecode.com).

I made some minor changes to the open source library that are specific to the app I am working on (there is no reason to commit the changes to googlecode.com and I have no intention of doing so).

I then added the entire solution (containing all 3 projects) to a different repository.

Everything is how I want it in the 2nd repository but, because the one library is still linked to the googlecode repository, ankhsvn and tortoisesvn show pending changes (I have confirmed that those pending changes are already committed to the new/2nd repository).

My question is...

Is there an easy way to detach that one project from the googlecode repository or will I have to start over (copy the solution, delete svn data, then re-add the solution)?

Comment: Don't really understand why you construct such working copy; you should use svn:externals in this particular case to get the part from google code. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the files versioned, no.